# How to put a variable as a href and variable text inside it? (Google maps info window)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am having trouble figuring out how to put dynamic links inside my google maps info window, and also wrapping some dynamic text with  tags.

How can I pass lurl to the a href, and place
`placeResultStringArray[0]+","+placeResultStringArray[1]+","+placeResultStringArray[2]+` inside the  tags?

Here is the code that I am working with:

```
function showDetails(placeResult, marker, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    let placeInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    let rating = "None";
    if (placeResult.rating) rating = placeResult.rating;
    let placeResultStringArray = placeResult.formatted_address.split(",");
    let lurl = `https://bajablast.live/${placeResultStringArray[0]}`;
    placeInfowindow.setContent(
      "<div><strong>" +
        placeResult.name +
        "</strong><br>" + 
        <a href = ${lurl}> +
        placeResultStringArray[0]+","+placeResultStringArray[1]+","+placeResultStringArray[2]+
        </a> +
        "<br>" +
        "Rating: " +
        rating +
        "</div>"
    );
    placeInfowindow.open(marker.map, marker);
    currentInfoWindow.close();
    currentInfoWindow = placeInfowindow;
    // showPanel(placeResult);
  } else {
    console.log("showDetails failed: " + status);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace

```
<a href = ${lurl}> +
```

with

```
`<a href="${lurl}">` +
```

...or with

```
"<a href=\"" + lurl + "\">" +
```

...or with

```
"<a href='" + lurl + "'>" +
```

You also need to wrap `</a>` in quotes, as you want it parsed as string, not as a javascript expression (which would result in an error).

Until you get to the point where you can easily figure out the output of a string concatenation, the easiest way to figure out what's wrong is to `console.log()` the current value and modify your code until the logged string is the desired result.

Most likely, your `setContent` should look like this:

```
placeInfowindow.setContent(
  "<div><strong>" +
  placeResult.name +
  "</strong><br>" + 
  `<a href="${lurl}">` +
  placeResultStringArray[0] + 
  "," + 
  placeResultStringArray[1] +
  "," + 
  placeResultStringArray[2] +
  "</a>" +
  "<br>" +
  "Rating: " +
  rating +
  "</div>"
);
```

which I would write as:

```
placeInfowindow.setContent(`
<div>
  <strong>
    ${placeResult.name}
  </strong>
  <br>
  <a href="${lurl}">
    ${[0,1,2].map(i => placeResultStringArray[i]).join(',')}
  </a>
  <br>
  Rating: ${rating}
</div>
`);
```

I find it easier to read/understand, hence modify.